# Laravel - User class not found exception

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to understand how to implement the separation of concerns in the Laravel documentation on the [Models & Libraries](http://www.laravel.com/docs/models) page. I renamed my models folder into 'malice' (my pc's computer name) to simulate a rename like it says on the site.

I understand that the class can't be found but this is my first time using Laravel and first time to ever hear of "separation of concerns" so please be patient with me. :)

Here's what I have:

```
// application/malice/entities/user.php
<?php namespace Malice\Entities;

class User {

    public $name;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}

// application/malice/services/user_doit.php
<?php namespace Malice\Services;

use Malice\Entities\User;

class User_Doit {

    public static function introduce(User $name){
        return "Hi, I'm {$name}";
    }

}
```

When I run in my controller:

```
$user = new User();
krumo($user); // I'm using krumo isntead of print_r
```

This is all I get:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Class 'User' not found
Location:

D:\xampp\virtual\laravel\application\controllers\test.php on line 29
```

**Update:**

This is what my start.php currently looks like:

```
Autoloader::directories(array(
    // path('app').'models',
    path('app').'libraries',
));

Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Malice' => path('app').'malice'
));
```

Comment: Have you adjusted the autoloading directories in `application/start.php`?

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to. But after renaming it to `path('app').'malice',` it still didn't work. If only the docs for this weren't so bare it would be great. It's like it tells you what it can do to show off then runs away before you can ask a question.

Comment: Since you're namespacing you might need to use `Autoloader::namespaces(array('Malice' => path('app').'malice'));`

Comment: Still same error. I updated my post to show what my `start.php` file currently looks like.

Comment: I forget how the autoloader works in L3. Perhaps try dropping it back a directory. So `array('Malice' => path('app'))`.

Comment: This is nothing to do with separation of concerns. You have a class not found error, and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, add the **User** class like this.

```
use Malice\Entities\User;

$user = new User();
krumo($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using:
new Malice\Entities\User instead of just new User?